Why the 3rd column of some packages in the yum list output were "installed" under the RHEL 6/7
In fact, there might be the following two sub-questions within the above problem title:
1) Whatever the development design of the rpm package structure could result in the null output of the repoquery -i ? 
2) Whether without the "from_repo" attribute in the rpm package structure could result in the "installed" via yum list ?
#
#  
# yum list installed|grep -i installed
Installed Packages
storcli.x86_64                     007.1108.0000.0000-1           installed     
# 
# 
# 
# yum list installed|grep -i zabbix
zabbix-agent.x86_64                4.0.2-1.el7                    @zabbix  
# 
# 
# 
# yum info storcli.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
Name        : storcli
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 007.1108.0000.0000
Release     : 1
Size        : 7.1 M
Repo        : installed
Summary     : Storage Command Line Tool.
URL         : http://www.avagotech.com
License     : AVAGO Technologies
Description : storcli is used to manage storage controllers.

# 
# 
# yumdb info storcli.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
storcli-007.1108.0000.0000-1.x86_64
# 
# 
# 
# repoquery -i  storcli.x86_64
# 
# 
# repoquery -i  storcli.x86_64
# 
# 
# yum info zabbix-agent.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
Name        : zabbix-agent
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.0.2
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 1.5 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : zabbix
Summary     : Zabbix Agent
URL         : http://www.zabbix.com/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : Zabbix agent to be installed on monitored systems.

# 
# 
# repoquery -i zabbix-agent.x86_64

Name        : zabbix-agent
Version     : 4.0.2
Release     : 1.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Size        : 1559464
Packager    : None
Group       : Applications/Internet
URL         : http://www.zabbix.com/
Repository  : zabbix
Summary     : Zabbix Agent
Source      : zabbix-4.0.2-1.el7.src.rpm
Description :
Zabbix agent to be installed on monitored systems.
# 
# 


Some yum subcmds do only just use the rpmdb to query ...,   especially for list installed and info.

#  
# grep -Ei "/var/lib/" /tmp/yi_strace_1.out|grep rpm|wc -l
57
#  
#  
# grep -Ei "/var/lib/" /tmp/yi_strace_1.out|grep rpm|tail
open("/var/lib/rpm/pubkeys", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/lib/rpm", W_OK)            = 0
access("/var/lib/rpm/__db.001", F_OK)   = 0
access("/var/lib/rpm/Name", F_OK)       = 0
stat("/var/lib/rpm/Name", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/lib/rpm/Name", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
open("/var/lib/rpm/Name", O_RDONLY)     = 8
stat("/var/lib/rpm/Name", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=40960, ...}) = 0
open("/var/lib/rpm/Name", O_RDONLY)     = 8
stat("//var/lib/rpm/Packages", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55042048, ...}) = 0
# 


The installed marker represents packages that were installed without using yum.  For example, if I do this:
# yumdownloader words
# rpm -ivh words-3.0-22.el7.noarch.rpm

Then I will see:
# yum list installed |grep words
words.noarch                              3.0-22.el7                   installed


If so,  why the "yum info storcli.x86_64" can still work fine though it was installed via rpm -i ...... ?

Because yum (and/or dnf) knows how to extract metadata from installed rpms.
